# How can I access network from terminal?

Tags: networking, command-line, dd-wrt

So I'm trying to recover from a hugely failed upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10.

I can get my system to boot to console but not to desktop. So from the console I'm trying to fix broken packages. But I cannot access my network.

I'm on the live cd now and I can connect to the wireless network.

Here is my chain of events from console when booting without live cd, trying to obtain network access -

```
~$ ifconfig wlan0 up
~$ iwlist wlan0 scan 
~$ iwconfig wlan0 essid "dd-wrt"
~$ dhclient wlan0
```

I should say my network is named dd-wrt, and it is unsecured

Do I need quotes on  like I have?

So home come this isn't connecting?

Comment: can you try wired ethernet? this might be easier ;)

Comment: nobody knows how?

Comment: I have used this guide before, on a server: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html

Comment: Or, for wireless: _Ubuntu: Configure Wireless From The Command Line_ http://www.stoltenow.com/archives/2006/12/ubuntu_configur.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not spare any more time trying to repair my upgrade so I deja duped my home folder and anything else I needed to a external drive and did a fresh install. Thanks anyway, and I will certainly use the links provided above in the future.